# Jenkins: Build with Parameters button keeps disappearing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

```
...


pipeline.aws(configMap) {

properties([
        parameters([
                extendedChoice(name: 'built_version', type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'qa built version to deploy', visibleItemCount: 10, groovyScript:
                        '''def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my-demo-app-build-deploy-qa/master')
                           return job.builds.findResults { it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS ? it.getNumber().toInteger() : null }''')
        ])
])


    node('myimage') {
            stage('Checkout') {
                ...
            }
            stage(...){
                ...
            }
            stage(...) {
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

I am using the "Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In" to fetch the successful build number from the job 'my-demo-app-build-deploy-qa/master' to this job to promote it to the next environment. However, the `Build with Parameters` button keeps reverting back to `Build Now` causing an unnecessary failed build.

Once the job is triggered with `Build Now`, the button changes to `Build with Parameters` and everything works fine for a few hours.

Comment: Since your parameters ared declared in your pipeline, Jenkins can't know them at the beginning until your run it just once. The first build fail because parameters are missing in some steps. Then, the `Build with Parameters` is available and you can run it successfully.

Comment: It's ok if I have to do it just for the first build. But the options keeps disappearing every few hours.

Comment: What type of pipeline are you using ? Did the pipeline change during this time ?

Comment: @fmdaboville Found out that it was a problem with a seeder job that was refreshing this job from being parameterized to non-parameterized. Thanks.

Comment: @Saif what was the issue with the seeder job?

Comment: @drcomputer The seeder job was setting the default properties. So the properties from the job's Jenkinsfile was getting overridden.

Comment: Gotcha - good to know the order of prioritization there! Thanks for your reply on this year-old thread.